# Flex: Accessing video content over local network

Tags: apache-flex

I am having a strange issue in my flex app. I have a `Video` element that loads an FLV file from the same directory as the SWF app. If I move my SWF and FLV to a local directory on my computer and load the SWF in my browser, the video plays without any issues. However, if I move the same collection of files (SWF, FLV, HTML) to a network share, the video no longer loads.

I am loading video using a `NetConnection` and `NetStream` and calling `video.attachNetStream(stream)` on my `Video` object.

```
stream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
stream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
var video:Video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(stream);
```

In my `netStatusHandler()` callback I get an event status of: **NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound**.

Again, I only have this issue when loading content from a network share.

Comment: Are you serving these off a web server?  Or loading the file using a local system path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because of the security sandbox since now your application is not 'local' anymore, the security sandbox policy is activated.  There's 2 things you can do; you can add that network share/swf into your security sandbox through the [security settings page](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) or you can 'share' this over an http server (apache).

You should read up more on [security sandboxes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_04.html).